# memory leaks this code

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

```
htmPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"barcode" ofType:@"html"];
params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"?data=%@",numberTextField.text];
fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmPath] absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:params]];

[self.barView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileURL]];
```

////htmpath,params are strings.

///fileurl is nsurl and in this i m calling appending two strings for the result.
///numberTextField.text   is the textfield that will use this html for further functionality.

Answer (score 4):

you have allocated the "params" and did not released it.

```
params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"?data=%@",numberTextField.text];
```

you should release every allocated object.

```
[params release];
```